# preg_replace para a preg_replace_callback

Tags: php

Como fazer a transição da função `preg_replace` para a `preg_replace_callback` nesse caso? Uso as *arrays* por que futuramente posso adicionar continuação..

```
preg_replace(

    array(
        '/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?´ªìîëí]))/'
    ),

    array( '' . $this -> makelink( $1 ) . '' ), $text
);
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione o código do método `$this->makelink` e também a declaração da variável `$text`.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de você querer usar esta função, no caso, o array de padrões regex, não seria para você criar uma continuação do link, mas sim padrões de link diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez você tenha se confundido quanto ao propósito de [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

[preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) serve principalmente para efetuar substituições regulares complexas de forma mais manutenível e compatível com futuras versões do PHP, por dispensar o uso ocasional do [Modificador PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval) **e**, encapsulando toda a lógica numa [Closure](http://www.php.net/Closure).

No seu caso seria algo assim:

```
$line = preg_replace_callback(

    'sua_er',

    function( $matches ) {

        // Faz alguma coisa com $matches[ 0 ] e retorna
    },

    $line
);
```

Porém, *makelink* já é um método de uma classe você já tem parte daquilo que [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) provê que é o encapsulamento e separação lógica.

Se vale a ressalva, porém, eu apenas removeria aquelas concatenações no segundo array que não me parecem certas.